# Washing machine with ammonia like odor

Tags: washing-machine, smell

My washing machine started to emit a very strong ammonia-odor.
I googled around and seems that this happens when doing laundry at low temperatures.
I do my laundry at 40 degrees (can't even remember last time I did at 60).
I did 2-3 runs without any clothes at 95 degrees.
The odor decreased a lot but still needs more so that it smells fresh.
Can I use vinegar or some other trick to make the odor go away faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you run the hot empty loads with some bleach in the water? Bleach smell may be strong if you use too much but it should help get rid of any residual organic slime left from low temperature washing.

If you do not like to use the bleach try to have the hot empty load run with regular laundry detergent plus a scoop of OxyClean powder.

Comment: I don't have bleach around at the moment and I don't use it too much to be honest. Can I use white vinegar instead? Otherwise I can do the regular laundry detergent (plus this powder)

Comment: I cannot say if the vinegar would help or not. I never considered vinegar in a cloths washer before. The acid nature of vinegar seems like it could be hard on the metal parts of your washer. Maybe if just used once and well rinsed afterwords this would be of zero concern.